# Can you simplify Else If?

Tags: python

Currently working on a project from school. And they want us to take a users input and display their grades.

Now I am just being curious here, but is there any way to make this more simple? I feel like this could easily get out of hand.

My first thought was instead of creating each grade as a variable. You could make it an array. Could you then create some sort of loop that will check instead of creating an if else?

Sorry if this isn't possible. Just very curious about how i could improve on this.

```
> Grades = [
    '9',
    '8',
    '7', 
    '6', 
    '5',
    '4',
    '3', 
    '2', 
    '1', 
    'U'
]

Component_1 = int(input("Enter your Component 1 mark here: "))
if Component_1 <= 9:
    print(f"You got the grade {Grades[9]} ")
elif Component_1 <= 17:
    print(f"You got the grade {Grades[8]}")
elif Component_1 <= 25:
    print(f"You got the grade {Grades[7]}")
elif Component_1 <= 34:
    print(f"You got the grade {Grades[6]}")
```

The task I was originally asked to do:
[image]

Comment: This is a question better suited for [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Everything goes in steps of `8`, so just divide by 8.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "My first thought was instead of creating each grade as a variable. You could make it an array. Could you then create some sort of loop that will check instead of creating an if else?" Well, did you **try it**? What do you imagine are the logical steps involved, and where do you get stuck if you try to write the code yourself?

Comment: Sorry  I am new to Stack overflow.

Comment: For a general approach, make an array of the cutoff scores for each grade, then search it.

Comment: But in the assignment the steps aren't consistent. Use an array or dictionary.

Comment: @paddy How would I search in an array?

Comment: Well, earlier you thought that it might use some kind of loop. What kinds of loop do you know about? Which seems more practical for looking at each element of a list (we don't call them arrays in Python)? Once you are looking at an element, can you write the code to tell whether it's the right one? If you put that code into a loop, doesn't that already solve the problem? *Where exactly are you stuck*? Have you written code with loops before?

Comment: A loop or list comprehension should do the trick.  What won't help is taking shortcuts in the learning process.  Python is notoriously accessible.  You can do experiments live in the Python shell.  There's so much documentation about how to do stuff in Python.  Asking here without making any attempts is basically asking for free tutoring.

Comment: Since the instructions are explicit about using `if` statements, there's probably no simpler way to do it.  It could be that they explicitly want to teach you the bad way before exposing you to the better way.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list of tuples that map the component score to the grade.

```
comp1_grades = [(9, 'U'), (17, '1'), (25, '2'), ...]

for max_score, grade in comp1_grades:
    if Component_1 <= max_score:
        print(f"You got the grade {grade}")
        break
```

Comment: Your answer is cool.  You should, however, include the case where the entered value exceeds all `max_score` values, as I assume that this should print something, an error at least if no value should ever exceed the final cutoff.

Answer (score 1):

If the `Grades` structure is provided, here's how to do what you want without modifying it:

```
grade_cutoffs = [9, 17, 25, 34, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88]
for i in range(len(grade_cutoffs)):
    if Component_1 <= grade_cutoffs[i]:
        print(f"You got the grade {Grades[9-i]}")
        break
else:
    print(f"You got the grade {Grades[0]}")
```

Some sample runs:

```
Enter your Component 1 mark here: 45
You got the grade 5 

Enter your Component 1 mark here: 3
You got the grade U 

Enter your Component 1 mark here: 5555
You got the grade 9
```

Or, if you can assume the simple nature of `Grades` to be what you show here, then you don't even need that structure:

```
grade_cutoffs = [9, 17, 25, 34, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88]
for i in range(len(grade_cutoffs)):
    if Component_1 <= grade_cutoffs[i]:
        print(f"You got the grade {i if i else 'U'}")
        break
else:
    print(f"You got the grade 9")
```

which gives the same results.

Answer (score 0):

We can even solve  this by using dictionary too, similar to tuples provided by @Barmar

Here Grades is a dictionary which will store baseline scores and grades.
looping on dictionary we can fetch its key:value.
comparing input with key, based on if condition show the grade if it is neither < or > it will check on another value because it is in a loop, once matched it will break.

**if user enters more than range for eg 1000 they will get to see out of range marks message**

Note : further baseline scores and grades needs to be added in Grades dictionary

```
Grades={
     9:'U',
     17:'1'
}
Component_1 = int(input("Enter your Component 1 mark here: "))
count = 0
for key, values in Grades.items():
     if Component_1 <= key:
          count = count + 1
          print(f"You got:{values}")
          break
if count == 0 :
     print('you entered out of range marks')
```